# How to preprocess videos for a Conv3D Model

Tags: python, video, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I have this Conv3D model in Keras:

```
model = Sequential(

Conv3D(32, (3,3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=self.input_shape),
MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)),
Conv3D(64, (3,3,3), activation='relu'),
MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)),
Conv3D(128, (3,3,3), activation='relu'),
Conv3D(128, (3,3,3), activation='relu'),
MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)),
Conv3D(256, (2,2,2), activation='relu'),
Conv3D(256, (2,2,2), activation='relu'),
MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2), strides=(1, 2, 2)),

Flatten(),
Dense(1024)),
Dropout(0.5),
Dense(1024),
Dropout(0.5)),
Dense(self.nb_classes, activation='softmax')
)
```

This model is based on this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.0767.pdf

Which is the best way to preprocess video data to be predicted using this Conv3D?

I wrote this function to extract frames from each video of the UCF-101:

```
def frame_writer(pathIn, pathOut, class_name):
"""
This function will read videos and write frames in a new dataset
args:
    pathIn -> base dataset of videos
    pathOut -> destination folder for the frames ('data/path')
"""
#creating output path if it not exists
try:
  if not os.path.exists(pathOut + '/' + class_name):
    os.makedirs(pathOut + '/' + class_name)

  else:
    pass
except:
  print('Invalid path!')

#getting the list containing all files from the directory
pathIn_files = glob.glob(pathIn + '\\' + class_name + '\\' + '*.avi')
video_limit = len(pathIn_files)

#iterating over all files
for i, j in zip(pathIn_files, range(len(pathIn_files))):
  #getting the names from file paths
    base_name = os.path.basename(pathIn_files[j])
    file_name = base_name[0:-4] #taking only the file name (without extension)

    #getting the frames
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    count = 0
    success = True
    while success:
      success,image = vidcap.read()
      print ('Read a new frame: ', success)
      cv2.imwrite(pathOut + '\\' + class_name + "\\%s_frame%d.jpg" % (file_name, count), image)
      count += 1
print('Done!')
```

Now i have my dataset of frames like this:

FOLDER: data

-SUBFOLDER: train

--SUBFOLDER: class1

---frame1_video1_class1.jpg

---frame2_video1_class1.jpg

---frame3_video1_class1.jpg

...

---frameN_videoN_class1.jpg

--SUBFOLDER: class2

---frame1_video1_class2.jpg

---frame2_vide1_class2.jpg

---frame3_video1_class2.jpg

...

---frameN_videoN_class2.jpg

-SUBFOLDER: test

--SUBFOLDER: class1

---frame1_video1_class1.jpg

---frame2_video1_class1.jpg

---frame3_video1_class1.jpg

...

---frameN_videoN_class1.jpg

--subfolder: class2

---frame1_video1_class2.jpg

---frame2_video1_class2.jpg

---frame3_video1_class2.jpg

...

---frameN_videoN_class2.jpg

So i have all the frames from all the videos inside a folder corresponding to its class.

I have to pass it to my Conv3D model using ImageDataGenerator from keras functions?

So, in this case, pass each frame from each video from each class one at time?

Or i have to do this in another way?

I just need to predict videos using this model!

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to put all of your frames into one big tensor, label them accordingly, and use this as input to your Keras model. The number of frames you have in the tensor will be your batch size.

Comment: Good! I'll try this! Do you have some tutorial link for this?